# Prove or disprove: Special linear group is subgroup of orthogonal group

Tags: orthogonal-matrices

Let $H$ be the special linear group. $H=\{M \in M_n(\mathbb{K}): det(M) = 1\}$. Is $H$ a subgroup of the orthogonal group?

Counterexample:

Let $A = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Then $det(A) = 1$. But $AA^T \neq Id$. So $A$ isn't orthonormal.

Is that a valid counterexample?

Comment: The statement is ambiguous, since there is no such thing as *the* orthogonal group. But, yes, that proves that $SL(n,\mathbb K)\varsubsetneq O(n,\mathbb K)$.

Comment: I wasn't sure about this either. I assumed that they mean all matrices which are orthogonal. Thanks!